# Вернуть предыдущее изображение при повторном клике

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, vegas

Делаю переключатель фоновых изображений, мне нужно сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку переключался фон и при повторном клике на ту же кнопку он возвращал на фон предыдущее изображение.
**[Код с codepen прикладываю](https://codepen.io/nosferatu-id/pen/YzXbvOv)**

```js
$('.frame').vegas({
  preloadImage: true,
  autoplay: false,
  cover: true,
  transition: 'fade',
  transitionDuration: 250,
  slides: [
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583771803077-e512cbd2059c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583858815652-56b390b3a3e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584605376366-63f17a36e99e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585432840537-b8bd65bc6b6a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'}
  ]
})
$('.toggle-slide:nth-child(1)').on('click', function() {
  $('.frame').vegas('jump', 0)
})
$('.toggle-slide:nth-child(2)').on('click', function() {
  $('.frame').vegas('jump', 1)
})
$('.toggle-slide:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
  $('.frame').vegas('jump', 2)
})
$('.toggle-slide:nth-child(4)').on('click', function() {
  $('.frame').vegas('jump', 3)
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.frame {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button class="toggle-slide">1</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">2</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">3</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">4</button>
  <div class="frame"></div>
</main>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.4/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.4/vegas.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.frame').vegas({
  preloadImage: true,
  autoplay: false,
  cover: true,
  transition: 'fade',
  transitionDuration: 250,
  slides: [
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583771803077-e512cbd2059c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583858815652-56b390b3a3e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584605376366-63f17a36e99e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'},
    {src: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1585432840537-b8bd65bc6b6a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ'}
  ]
});

$('.toggle-slide').on('click', function() {
  //console.log($('.frame').vegas('current'));
  var c = $('.frame').vegas('current');
  var i = $('.toggle-slide').index(this);
  var p = parseInt($('.frame').data("prev"));
  if (i == c && !isNaN(p)) {
    $('.frame').vegas('jump', p);
    $('.frame').data("prev", "");
  } else {
    $('.frame').vegas('jump', i);
    $('.frame').data("prev", c);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.frame {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button class="toggle-slide">1</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">2</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">3</button>
  <button class="toggle-slide">4</button>
  <div class="frame"></div>
</main>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.4/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.4/vegas.min.js"></script>
```